# How to Center Bar in Flot Char js

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, flot, flotr2

i have, some problem with flot.js, in my chart xaxis is not center with the bar, i try with align: 'center' but it's not work, what I want is the xaxis (date label) exactly below the chart
this is my code

```
 $.plot('#grafik-presensi', [data], {
        series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.6,
                    align:'center',
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                            opacity: 0.9
                        }, {
                            opacity: 0.9
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            colors: ['#25476a'],
            yaxis: {
                },
            xaxis: {
                    ticks: ticks,
                    
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                tickColor: '#eeeeee',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                position: 'nw'
            },
            tooltip: {
                show: true,
                content: 'Presensi %x, Jumlah %y'
            }

    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: What are the x-values of your data and ticks? If you are using datetime values this could be a timezone issue (local time vs. UTC).

Comment: it's datetime sir, and i'm from indonesian (GMT +7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data x-values and your ticks seem to be shifted corresponding to your timezone (GMT +7). You need to make sure both the data and the ticks us local time or both use UTC. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information.

If it is not possible to use the same timezone for data and ticks, you can also shift the ticks manually by adding 7 hours to them.